# Unable to execute a CSS transform. Can someone see and help me out?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, responsive, css-transforms

I am very new to the whole of CSS and web development. I have been learning by looking at the examples on W3 and Codepen. I have prepared a flexbox inside swipeable slides. I want each card to be zoomed in and show a description. I am also putting the links here.. can someone please explain where I went wrong?

[Here's is my code](https://codepen.io/MeghSham/pen/xxgRLmx)

I want a translazeZ transform on each tab in my flexbox. I want each tab to be expanded as a larger section.

[This is an example](https://codepen.io/MeghSham/pen/jOyLrgR)

```
    .card{ 
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-grow: 4;
      font-size: 22px;
      padding: 25px; 
      margin: 15px; 
      color: white;
      border-radius: 5px; 
      background: blue;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transition: transform 0.5s; 
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center; 
    }

    .card div {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 6px;
      background: blue;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      align-items: center;
      transition: 1s;
      color: white; 
    }
    .card .des {
      display: none;  
    }  
    .card.flipped { 
       transform: translateZ(100px);
    }
```

Comment: Pleae add your code in a stack snipped to your question instead of linking to other pages. This question is still here when the external page eventually is gone and then no one can see your code anymore...

Comment: Alright... I will do that

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the `transform: scale` property. I think this is what you need ;)
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale()

```css
transform: scale(2); /* --> Gives you the double resized of normal item*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, but you have to wrap the description in an element (for example 'span') and that again in an container (for example 'div') for centering with flex, since toggle() does `display: block;`.

```js
$('.container').on('click', function() {
  $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
  $('.des').toggle();
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 4;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.card div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.card .des {
  display: none;
}

.card.flipped {
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div>
      <h5>Integration</h5><br>
      <div class="des">
        <div>
          <span>Description, Yo, what up?</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am able to do this for one card. But I am trying to build a flexbox and I want each card in a flex box to come to the center and be zoomed.

Comment: Then is now a good moment for adding the html to your question so that we can see what you want and don't need to guess what it could be ;)...